# Applet Web Deployment problems

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7, jclouds

So basically I have made a Java applet that works 100% when I simply run the applet file directly, however when I attempt to have it run with a web service, it fails. I have discovered that by removing anything that uses external libraries seems to get it to function correctly.

I am using jClouds libraries and these seem to be the problem. Perhaps they are not being included the the .JAR used to run the applet in the web service. Is there any way to include all these external libraries so that the web service will function properly?

Im using netbeans to run and compile my programs in case that is relevent...

Answer (score 0):

can you clarify the question on what exactly isn't working, and how you've isolated jclouds as the problem?  maybe a gist with code or how you are building things + an error?